# How to set variable name of controller class so that all modelview can access that variable value?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, local

I am using Spring-Mvc in my wab-site where user can change language my
project is working fine i just need  improvment in my coding i dont
have too much knowledge of spring -mvc

Source code of my controller class is given below

```
@Controller
public class ContentController {

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public ModelAndView sriWap(){

        Locale locale2 = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        String lang_name = locale2.getDisplayLanguage();

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("language",lang_name);
        modelAndView.setViewName("sriWap");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/contentCat")
    public ModelAndView content_cat_desc(){
    Locale locale2 = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        String lang_name = locale2.getDisplayLanguage();

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("language",lang_name);
        modelAndView.setViewName("content_cat_desc");
        return modelAndView;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/content")
    public ModelAndView content(){
    Locale locale2 = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        String lang_name = locale2.getDisplayLanguage();

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("language",lang_name);
        modelAndView.setViewName("content");
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

As you can see i am writing the same code in all Methods to get the
selected language

```
Locale locale2 = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
String lang_name = locale2.getDisplayLanguage();
```

I dont want to write above code in all methods i want to write above
code only for one time so that all methods can use the value of
'lang_name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@ModelAttribute` annotation.

```
@Controller
public class ContentController {

    @ModelAttribute
    public void addCommon(Model model){
        Locale locale2 = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        String lang_name = locale2.getDisplayLanguage(); 
        model.addAttribute("language",lang_name);       

        //... add another common attributes
    }

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public ModelAndView sriWap(){
        return new ModelAndView("sriWap");
    }

    ....
}
```

Spring will add `"language"` attribute to the model for every mapped method automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Your right, where is a easy way in spring, which prevents this code duplication across your controller request methods. Your looking for `@ModelAttribute` about a method: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods

So you have to extraxt this code duplication into a single method, which is annontated with `@ModelAttribute` like this:

```
@ModelAttribute("language")
public String getLocaleLanguage() {
    Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
    return locale.getDisplayLanguage();
}
```

When this "language" `@ModelAttribute` also is needed across other `@Controllers` you want to extract it into a `@ControllerAdvice`

Comment: Share data with `@ControllerAdvice` is acceptable approach. But much more easier to create parent class with `@ModelAttribute` method, and inherit all controllers from this parent class.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the properties as instance variables and make use of 
init method to initialise its values.

```
 @PostConstruct
 public void init() {
 locale2 = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
 lang_name = locale2.getDisplayLanguage();     
 }
```